# Tracking down a spam redirection: ?oem=

Tags: joomla-1.5, hack

I have a rather old Joomla site http://qlectives.eu running Joomla 1.5.17 (it is not longer in use but I want to keep it available for anyone wanting to look back at it; therefore I don't want to upgrade to 3.x if I can avoid it).  Generally it works fine, but I have discovered that http://qlectives.eu/?oem=adobe-incopy-cs5-mac gives a 302 redirection to a site selling fake Adobe products.  Obviously I want to stop this, but I have no idea where this redirection is being generated.  I've checked the .htaccess file, which looks fine. Where else should I be looking?  Is there a known hack that does this?

Comment: if it's for archive only, you can convert you site to HTML using https://www.httrack.com/
It will convert you site to HTML

Answer (score 2):

Really, get that Joomla installation at least up to the latest available release for that series, which would be [Joomla 1.5.26](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.joomla.org%2Fannouncements%2Frelease-news%2F5419-joomla-1526-released.html&ei=MO2QVe2vNcz5UrepgIgO&usg=AFQjCNEbLJFtY7vurqvwXrrasFLKaFiE3Q&sig2=nMLuaZyMv_qLBF84X1PCSg&bvm=bv.96783405,d.d24)
There is also a [community patch](https://docs.joomla.org/Security_hotfixes_for_Joomla_EOL_versions) which fixes a security issue found after Joomla 1.5 went EoL.

After that, make sure to check the whole site for hacked files. Refer to the [official documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Security_Checklist/You_have_been_hacked_or_defaced) what you should do when you detect a hacked site.
You can request paid service from [MyJoomla](https://myjoomla.com/) or similar services who can clean your site.